# How to Split a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, split, substring

I am in a project where I need to split a JavaScript variable into individual values.

My variable looks like this :

```
["ch  au"] or ["ch"]or ["au"]
```

I want to check whether ch or au is present in that variable.  If present, it needs to be saved to another variable.

How to check wheather ch and au are present in a specific variable.

Comment: You could do this by regex match method. Get the index from the token you are looking for and then use the substring method with this index.

Comment: If you have to work with such unorganized data there's really something wrong in your design.

Comment: use jquery method split

Comment: What about learning Javascript ?

Comment: I am not strong in Javascript.But i did with the help of SLICE method in JS.Thank u all for your feedback.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but here are some pointers. :)

```
var myString = 'ch  au';

// Check if string contains string
if (myString.indexOf('ch') >= 0) {

// Split string (in this case by '  ')
var myArray = myString.split('  ');
// This returns an array that would look like: ['ch', 'au']

// Check if array contains string
if (myArray.indexOf('ch') >= 0) {

// Take individual value from an array
var newString = myArray[0];
```

Comment: This did the MAGIC what i need. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
var countryArray = str.split(" ");
```

This will split your string into an array. In this case your delimiter seems to be whitespace.